# Excel VBA Select Option Website Dropdown List and Click

Tags: html, excel, internet-explorer, web-scraping, vba

I am trying to copy the response from the website, but I have to select one of the options from the dropdown list so the page can refresh.

So far, I've managed to open IE and click the dropdown button, but I cannot select the option, don't know why. Please find the a sample of the code below.

```
Sub OpenWebSelectClickSaveHtmlFile()
    Dim URL As String
    URL = "http://formulaacademia.com.br/academia"
    Set myIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With myIE
        .navigate URL
        .Visible = True
        Do While .Busy = True Or .readyState <> 4
        Loop
        DoEvents
        Set selectitems = myIE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")
        For Each i In selectitems
            i.Click
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Rgds

Comment: Put `DoEvents` inside of the `Do ... Loop`. What data finally you intent to retrieve from the response? Using XHR instead of IE may be better solution.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this.  Change the relevant parts to suit your needs.

```
Sub passValueToComboBox1()
   Dim ie  As Object
   Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement

   Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
   ie.Visible = True
   ie.navigate "http://peterschleif.bplaced.net/excel/combobox/index.php"
   While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

   Set oHTML_Element = ie.document.getElementsByName("selectedReportClass")(0)
   If Not oHTML_Element Is Nothing Then oHTML_Element.Value = "com.db.moap.report.FUBU7"

   For Each oHTML_Element In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
      If oHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
   Next
End Sub
```